# MySQL REPLACE without all fields provided

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sphinx

I have mysql query to replace some records:

```
REPLACE INTO product_core
(id, title, description, category_id)
VALUES (2, 'new_title', 'new_description', 33)
```

Can I do the same, but not providing all needed values? Example:

```
REPLACE INTO product_core
(id, title, description, category_id)
VALUES (2, 'new_title', 'new_description') #no category_id
```

Got `error wrong number of values here near`

I want to bulk replace many records, but I do not want to query all fields before. In this example, I want to update category_id for some records, but not for all.

```
REPLACE INTO product_core
(id, title, description, category_id)
VALUES (2, 'new_title_2', 'new_description_2'), #no category_id
(3, 'new_title_3', 'new_description_3', 34) #with category_id
```

Is it real to do this? Replace some fields for one record and other fields for second record in one query.

Or if is it real to provide special variable meaning that some fields will be the same as before replace (category_id)?

```
VALUES (2, 'new_title_2', 'new_description_2', @category_id_same_as_before)
```

Comment: is it possible to leave out the field then? REPLACE INTO product_core(id, title, description) values (2, 'new_title', 'new_description'). Looks like not too difficult to implement.

Comment: @ruud I don't think you read the whole question

Comment: What does this question have to do with `ruby`, `ruby-on-rails` or `sphinx`? Unless the tags are actually relevant to the question, I would suggest deleting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't omit these columns from a `REPLACE` command, unless it is the default value for the column.

According to [the documentation](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html):

> Any missing columns are set to their default values. [...] You cannot refer to values from the current row and use them in the new row.

It may be better to use a standard `UPDATE` command instead, which *can* reference the current column value.

Comment: I think you are right. I can use UPDATE, because i do not need delete records to update them. Could I make bulk UPDATE with different WHERE statements in one query?

Comment: I added tags 'ruby','sphinx' because I'm working with it: Rails->thinking-sphinx->Mysql->Manticore(Sphinx). Maybe someone who worked with them knows solution.

Comment: @НиколайАгеев Like I said, how is that actually relevant to the question? You didn't provide any information about the `ruby` code, or wider context of the problem.... If it's relevant, then could you explain how/why? Maybe you're also using `vim` as a text editor, but there's no information to imply that this is relevant either.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not saying "`ruby`/`rails`/`sphinx` isn't relevant", I'm saying "Don't add a tag, without mentioning what relevance the tag has". For example, anyone looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby will have seen your question - but what you've asked is purely to do with `MySQL`.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do the same, but not providing all needed values? Example:
>
> REPLACE INTO product_core (id, title, description, category_id) VALUES
>   (2, 'new_title', 'new_description') #no category_id

Yes, the correct query is:

```
REPLACE INTO product_core
(id, title, description)
VALUES (2, 'new_title', 'new_description') #no category_id
```

EDIT: As Tom commented below the above might be misleading as for the omitted columns default values will be used, not the ones set for the record which is being replaced.

> Is it real to do this? Replace some fields for one record and other fields for second record in one query.

It's not possible in MySQL. The column list is common for all the values sets.

> Or if is it real to provide special variable meaning that some fields
>   will be the same as before replace (category_id)?

It's perhaps possible, but not straightforward and not in all MySQL versions. In the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) they say: "You cannot refer to values from the current row and use them in the new row". 
In MySQL > 8.0.19 perhaps [VALUES(ROW)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html) can help. Or you can perhaps write you own UDF which does it.

Comment: Your first query is misleading, because it depends what you mean by "needed values". That query will create a new record with the **default** `category_id` value; there is no guarantee that this will have the same value as the previous `product_core` record that's being replaced.

Comment: @manticore-search Glad you answered, because I'm using Manticoresearch in my Rails project through thinking-sphinx gem (didn't find other gems). If I will use bulk UPDATE instead of REPLACE, won't it affects badly on Manticore index?

Comment: If you can use UPDATE in Manticore - use it as it's much cheaper resource-wise than REPLACE. UPDATE does in-place update while REPLACE adds a new record and marks the old one as deleted and given indexes are mostly immutable in Manticore it will cause a duplicate (in terms of resource consumption), so if you do lots of REPLACEs you might need to OPTIMIZE your index sooner than you would do it normally.

Bulk UPDATE is ok, but make sure you allow Manticore flush your updated attributes to disk (see FLUSH ATTRIBUTES and rt_flush_period)